# Resetting state on component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, components, jsx

I have a simple problem in React JS. I have two different click events, which switch the state of the component. The first one works perfectly, however I cannot get the second event to reset the component back to its original state. This is a stripped down version of my problem, so just know that I cannot move the click functions into the Child component.

```
class Parent extends Component{
  constructor(){
    this.state = {
      open: false
    }
    this.handleOpen = this.handleOpen.bind(this)
    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this)
  }
  handleOpen(){
    this.setState({open: true})
  }
  handleClose(){
    this.setState({open: false})
  }
  render(){
    return(
    <div>
      <Child onOpen={this.handleOpen} onClose={this.handleClose} />
      <Child onOpen={this.handleOpen} onClose={this.handleClose} />
      <Child onOpen={this.handleOpen} onClose={this.handleClose} />
      <Child onOpen={this.handleOpen} onClose={this.handleClose} />
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Like I said, the `handleOpen` function switches the state, but the `handleClose` does not switch it back. I can get a console log to show on the `handleClose` function, so I know that it does not have to do with how it is being hooked up to the Child Component. Am I missing something about how to reset a state value after it has already been switched. Thank you for your help!

Comment: you need to wrap your childs in a `<div></div>`

Comment: You're actually calling the functions in `render`. surely you mean to pass the function reference `onOpen={this.handleOpen}` <-- no parenthesis at end

Comment: Sorry, those were both typos. They have been fixed, but the problem still exists. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you trigger onOpen and onClose in the child component

Answer (score 0):

Here is How you have to do it!

```js
class Child extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
   }
   
   handleClick() {
      console.log(this.props.isOpen);
      if (this.props.isOpen) {
         this.props.onClose();
      } else {
         this.props.onOpen();
      }
   }

   render() {
      return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click ME</button>;
   }
}

class Parent extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false
    }
    this.handleOpen = this.handleOpen.bind(this)
    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this)
  }
  handleOpen(){
    this.setState({open: true})
  }
  handleClose(){
    this.setState({open: false})
  }
  render(){
    return(
    <div>
      <p>{this.state.open.toString()}</p>
      <Child onOpen={this.handleOpen} onClose={this.handleClose} isOpen={this.state.open} />
      <Child onOpen={this.handleOpen} onClose={this.handleClose} isOpen={this.state.open} />
      <Child onOpen={this.handleOpen} onClose={this.handleClose} isOpen={this.state.open} />
      <Child onOpen={this.handleOpen} onClose={this.handleClose} isOpen={this.state.open} />
    </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```